# How to prevent static files being included multiple times in Django templates?

Tags: django, include, django-templates

I have some template tags, which include some JavaScript and CSS files in the header. The problem is, that if I use these tags multiple times in the same template, the files are included multiple times unnecessarily. Is there a conventional way to prevent this from happening. (Like `#ifdef` in C++)

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to refactor something in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to organise your templates so that includes are made in the top hierarchy one, and only inherits from it in only the templates where you need it.

Django provides a very powerful mechanism to extends templates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/ but I don't think you actually need pre-processors-like guards, you can go most of the time work around them.

Maybe a most practical example of your need would help to see your problem.

Comment: I use template inheritance to include these files inside a block in my header. The problem is, that if I use multiple tags that extends my base, they end up included multiple times, because I use `block.super`. I need `block.super` because my tags have different dependencies.