# Highcharts/Django - Display a graph several time in a template

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, highcharts

I have Django implemented on my server and I'm using Highcharts to display some graphs.

**Here's what I'm doing:**

- Template A is making an AJAX call to "/my_url/"
- urls.py calls the method "my_method" from views.py
- Then, this method "render_to_response"a template B that contains the chart.
- Finally, the template A update a div with the content returned from views.py (Template B)

**My problem is**: when I run the AJAX request for the second time, I get a "Highcharts error #16". Maybe this is caused by the "script" tag that includes the highcharts library in the template B...

I really need some help. Thanks

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100417/how-to-prevent-static-files-being-included-multiple-times-in-django-templates). Most probably you are including Highcharts in AJAX, while  you should do this in Template A.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. If I relocate my script tag from template B to template A , the chart is not displayed.

Comment: Any errors in javascript console?

Comment: Besides the "Highcharts error #16", no.

Comment: Do you have this site live? If chart isn't displayed, there should be error behind this..